# merging tab delimited txt files based on column (which is header ) in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sh

Im having two text files which contains million records , all the records are tab delimited , how we can merge these two files based on same header(column)?

file:1

```
    LogEntryTime              nameId       PartnerId        
    2021-06-05T15:00:53 07    5lsddf        qyutxwr
```

file:2

```
        nameId  GroupId  compnayId
        5lsddf  l4buafm   0rd33cs
```

output like this:

```
    LogEntryTime              nameId       PartnerId    GroupId  compnayId
    2021-06-05T15:00:53 07    5lsddf        qyutxwr     l4buafm   0rd33cs
```

Tried this but not working:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | nameId -s $'\t' -t
```

and

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt |  awk -F '\t' '{print $ list the all columns name here}'
```

awk one which is working but need to mention all the column numbers there.

is there any other solution help me out.

thanks in advance

Comment: I would probably use a database for that.

Comment: in shell script how we can achieve that?

Comment: I don't think this will be easy. Many loops, and it will be slow.

Comment: for hundreds of records also use the same procedure?

Comment: If the order of the records is identical in all text files (i.e. record 2 of file1 maches record 2 of file2 etc), then your awk command with paste will cut it. Better add that info to your question. I was assuming that data need to be matched, forexample, `nameid 5lsddf` is record 1 in file1, but record *x* in file 2.

Comment: same column will cut in the second file merge with first file. that's all

Comment: can you help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files are properly constructed tab separated (TSV) files, then you can use `csvjoin` from the Python-based `csvkit` package.

Ex. given:

```
$ head file1.tsv file2.tsv | cat -A
==> file1.tsv <==$
LogEntryTime^InameId^IPartnerId$
2021-06-05T15:00:53 07^I5lsddf^Iqyutxwr$
$
==> file2.tsv <==$
nameId^IGroupId^IcompnayId$
5lsddf^Il4buafm^I0rd33cs$
```

(`cat -A` to make the tabs visible, as `^I`) then

```
$ csvjoin -I -t -c nameId file1.tsv file2.tsv
LogEntryTime,nameId,PartnerId,GroupId,compnayId
2021-06-05T15:00:53 07,5lsddf,qyutxwr,l4buafm,0rd33cs
```

To get the output back in TSV format, use `csvformat` from the same package:

```
$ csvjoin -I -t -c nameId file1.tsv file2.tsv | csvformat -T
LogEntryTime    nameId  PartnerId       GroupId compnayId
2021-06-05T15:00:53 07  5lsddf  qyutxwr l4buafm 0rd33cs
```

Note that `-I` disables type inference - which can sometimes behave unexpectedly, especially with datetime fields.

---

Even simpler, using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#reference) (available from the universe repository, as package `miller`):

```
$ mlr --tsv join -f file1.tsv -j nameId then reorder -f LogEntryTime file2.tsv
LogEntryTime    nameId  PartnerId       GroupId compnayId
2021-06-05T15:00:53 07  5lsddf  qyutxwr l4buafm 0rd33cs
```

The `reorder` is necessary because by default `mlr join` outputs the common field first (just like the system `join` command). Note that for unsorted input, the whole of `file1.tsv` will be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 2):

Loop one of the files into an array and replace the first field of the second file (which is `nameId`) with the array index that correlates to the common field.

```
awk -F \\t+ -vOFS=\\t 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next} {$1=a[$1]}1' file{1,2}.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With this particular set of data:

```bsh
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
    NR == FNR {f1[$2] = $0; next}
    {$1 = f1[$1]; print}
' file{1,2}.txt
```

Only the join field ($2 in file1, $1 in file2) is mentioned.

Produces the tab-separated output

```
LogEntryTime    nameId  PartnerId   GroupId compnayId
2021-06-05T15:00:53 07  5lsddf  qyutxwr l4buafm 0rd33cs
```

For pretty output, pipe into `| column -t -s $'\t'` to get

```
LogEntryTime            nameId  PartnerId  GroupId  compnayId
2021-06-05T15:00:53 07  5lsddf  qyutxwr    l4buafm  0rd33cs
```